# How to find data between specific range of dates

Tags: mysql

This is my table in a mysql database:

```
number_used   allocation_date       deallocation_date
1             1-4-2013 00:00:00     5-4-2013 00:00:00
2             6-4-2013 00:00:00     10-4-2013 00:00:00
3             11-4-2013 00:00:00    15-4-2013 00:00:00
1             16-4-2013 00:00:00    20-4-2013 00:00:00
```

There are three columns with no unique values. 1 number is used between date `1-4-2013` to `5-4-2013` and other likewise.

How can I find out the number_used between dates  `2-4-2013`  to  `14-4-2013`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple do this:-

```
SELECT number_used 
FROM table_name
WHERE '14-4-2013' >= `allocation_date ` AND `deallocation_date` >= '2-4-2013'
```

Comment: I did this. allocation_date<=2 AND deallocation_date>=14.

Comment: are these two things different

Comment: Nice copy of my answer, you even copied my "thetable" name ;)

Comment: @Rahul  :-Its working for me. I am not getting what I was trying before...thanks

Comment: @Jimmy:- I have updated my answer. Now I think that I dont deserve your downvote!! :(

Comment: but why are we comparing from_date to deallocation_date and to_date to allocation_date.

Comment: @user2686960:- Because that's what you wanted to find the data between the two date ranges.!! ;)

Comment: Because I don't like your answer, and it seems the original question asker doesn't understand it.

Comment: Yes. thats what I wanted. Initially was comparing allocated date to from_date and deallocated date to to_date.

Comment: @Jimmy:- Well that worked for him. Could you please tell me if I have done something wrong(For my knowledge improvement.)..Will be delighted to know if you can share anything which I missed.

Comment: I am not getting may be because I am saturated now and tring this since back 2 days. But the answer is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: I don't like the use of constants before variables, e.g. 5 < var is uglier than var > 5... never seen example code written like this... and you shoudn't copy/paste peoples answers, then try to edit things to make it look like you didn't (we can all see your edit history!)

Comment: @Jimmy:- Got your point Sir. !!! But the answer which helped OP was the one which I have written originally!! And it was just that I wanted to give an alternate solution. Although I got your point. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT number_used from thetable WHERE allocation_date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-05';
```

Comment: I used the one column, becase your data is buggy. What is the number_used between 5-4-2013 00:00:01 and 5-4-2013 23:59:59 ?

There isn't one if your ranging on both columns.

You should either put the ending times correctly, i.e. 23:59:59 or set this to a DATE column rather than TIMESTAMP.